# Selecting elements of a pandas dataframe that fall above a critical threshold

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas.df and I'm trying to remove all hypotheses that can be rejected.

Here is a snippet of the df in question:

```
    best value   p_value  
0      11.9549  0.986927  
1      11.9588  0.986896  
2      12.1185  0.985588  
3      12.1682  0.985161  
4      12.3907  0.983131  
5      12.4148  0.982899  
6      12.6273  0.980750  
7      12.9020  0.977680  
8      13.4576  0.970384  
9      13.5058  0.969679  
10     13.5243  0.969405  
11     13.5886  0.968439  
12     13.8025  0.965067  
13     13.9840  0.962011  
14     14.1896  0.958326  
15     14.3939  0.954424  
16     14.6229  0.949758  
17     14.6689  0.948783  
18     14.9464  0.942626  
19     15.1216  0.938494  
20     15.5326  0.928039  
21     17.7720  0.851915  
22     17.8668  0.847993  
23     17.9662  0.843822  
24     19.2481  0.785072  
25     19.5257  0.771242
```

I want to remove the elements with a p_value greater then a critical threshold `alpha` by selecting the ones fall below `alpha`. The p value is calculated using scipy.stats.chisqprob(chisq,df) where `chisq` is the chi squared statistic and `df` is the degrees of freedom. This is all done using the custom method `self.get_p_values` shown below.

```
def reject_null_hypothesis(self,alpha,df):
    assert alpha>0
    assert alpha<1
    p_value=self.get_p_values(df)  #calculates the data frame above
    return p_value.loc[p_value['best value']
```

Im then calling this method using:

```
PE=Modelling_Tools.PE_Results(PE_file)   #Modelling.Tools is the module and PE_Results is the class which is given the data 'PE_file' 
print PE.reject_null_hypothesis(0.5,25)
```

From what I've read this should do what I want but I'm new to pandas.df and this code returns the unchanged

Answer (score 2):

Are you getting any errors when you run this? I ask because:

```
print PE.reject_null_hypothesis(0.5, 25)
```

is passing into `reject_null_hypothesis()` `25`, an `int` object instead of a `pandas.DataFrame` object, in the last argument position.

(Apologies. I would respond with this as a comment instead of an answer, but I only have 46 reputation at the moment, and 50 is needed to comment.)

Comment: HI Andy - no there is no error being produced. Python just returns the unmodified dataframe

Comment: Thanks for the upvote! Gah, no newlines in comments lol. I would look into how `get_p_values(df)` uses the dataframe then, since you're passing 25 into it, and not a dataframe. Edit(s): newbie commenter

Answer (score 2):

refer [indexging with boolean array](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label)

```
df[ df.p_value < threshold ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a simple way to do what I want. Here is the code for those who want to know.

```
def reject_null_hypothesis(self,alpha,df):
    '''
    alpha = critical threshold for chisq statistic
    df=degrees of freedom
    values below this critical threshold are rejected.
    values above this threshold are not 'proven' but
    cannot be rejected and must therefore be subject to 
    further statistics 
    '''
    assert alpha>0
    assert alpha<1
    p_value=self.get_p_values(df)
    passed= p_value[p_value.loc[:,'p_value']>alpha].index
    return p_value[:max(passed)]
```